# How can I create a symlink which points to another symlink?

Tags: linux, ssh, symbolic-link

Is there any way to create a symbolic link which points to another symbolic link?

I have link **A** (pointing to address1 = `/home/data/username/var`) in /home/data directory 
and I need to create link **B** in `/home directory` which is points to link A.

If I do `ln -nfs /home/B /home/data/A`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

The argument order is

```
ln -s link-target new-link
```

So you'd want

```
ln -s /home/data/A /home/B
       ^--existing  ^----new link
          file/link
```

---

Update: I'd forgotten the `-s` flag in my sample, so it was trying to create hard links, which WILL traverse symlinks to try and point at whatever the link is pointing at. With symlinks, you can nest them as deep as you want:

```
marc@panic:~/b$ touch z
marc@panic:~/b$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 marc marc 0 2011-10-31 13:36 z
marc@panic:~/b$ ln -s z y
marc@panic:~/b$ ln -s y x
marc@panic:~/b$ ln -s x w
marc@panic:~/b$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 marc marc 1 2011-10-31 13:36 w -> x
lrwxrwxrwx 1 marc marc 1 2011-10-31 13:36 x -> y
lrwxrwxrwx 1 marc marc 1 2011-10-31 13:36 y -> z
-rw-r--r-- 1 marc marc 0 2011-10-31 13:36 z
```

Comment: thanks! but doesn't work too, seems like symlink to another symlink cannot be created, I have a error 'Could not resolve symlink “httpdocuments”. file not found'

Comment: see the edit. forgot the -s flag.

Comment: It's working on my local but it doesn't on the server...

Comment: What's the OS on the server, and what filesystem type is it running on?

Comment: Its a DV on Media Temple running Red Hat Linus Enterprise. From the command line : `Linux version 2.6.9-023stab048.6-enterprise (root@rhel4-32) (gcc version 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2)) #1 SMP Mon Nov 17 19:09:18 MSK 2008`

Comment: And its working on my MAC OS

Comment: Any error messages from the redhat server? It works fine on the RHES boxes I've got access to (RHES 4u9)

Comment: possibly whatever file system you're using remotely doesn't support symlinks?

Comment: nothing, I gave up with symlinks. just changed documentroot apache settings, works fine now. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

The OP wants a symlink, `ln` does a hardlink. But other than that, you can make a symlink that points to anywhere, the target doesn't even have to exist. `man ln` is your friend :) I usually do `ln -s tgt src`, so `src` points to `tgt`.